# datepicker first date in array initial

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

The purpose of this code is to include only the dates within the array and to activate the first date as initial in the datepicker.

I was able to get the first key of the array, which in the case is the first date I need to be as initial.

I believe the problem is in the format of the date, since it is deconfiguring the datepicker.

Follow my code:

JAVASCRIPT

```
// datepicker
var availableDates = {
"19102017": [
    "09:00",
    "09:15",
    "09:45",
    "11:45",
    "14:00"
],
"20102017": [
    "09:30"
],
"21102017": [
    "14:00"
],
"22102017": [
    "11:45"
],
"23102017": [
    "09:00"
],
"24102017": [
    "09:15"
],
"25102017": [
    "09:30"
],
"26102017": [
    "09:45"
],
"27102017": [
    "10:00"
],
"28102017": [
    "10:15"
]
};

getMinDate(Object.keys(availableDates)[0]);

function returnavailableDates(){
    return availableDates;
}
function getMinDate(date) {
    console.log(date);
    return date;
}

function checkDateis(d) {
    var check = false;
    $.each(availableDates, function( key, value ) {
        if (d === key) {
            check = true;
        }
    });
    if(check) return true;
}
function available(date) {
    var dmy = $.datepicker.formatDate('dmyy', date);
    var check = checkDateis(dmy);

    if (check) {
        return [true, "", "Available"];
    }
    else {
        return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
    }
}


$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths   : true,
    selectOtherMonths : true,
    minDate           : 0,
    nextText          : '',
    prevText          : '',
    dateFormat        : 'dd-mm-yy',
    beforeShowDay     : available
})

.datepicker('setDate', getMinDate(Object.keys(availableDates)[0]))
```

fiddle for tests: https://jsfiddle.net/n2n4udkf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the problem is format of the date being passed to `setDate`.

You can fix the issue by formatting the date before passing it to `setDate`

```
function formatDate(date) {
    return date.slice(0,2) + '-' + date.slice(2,4) + '-' + date.slice(4);
}

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths   : true,
    selectOtherMonths : true,
    minDate           : 0,
    nextText          : '',
    prevText          : '',
    dateFormat        : 'dd-mm-yy',
    beforeShowDay     : available
})

.datepicker('setDate', formatDate(getMinDate(Object.keys(availableDates)[0])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just change `dateFormat` in `datepicker`'s init options:

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    ...
    dateFormat        : 'ddmmyy',
    ...
})
```

Documentation: [`formatDate()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate).

**Added**: Also, there is an error in `available()` function:

```js
var dmy = $.datepicker.formatDate('dmyy', date);
```

It should be:

```js
var dmy = $.datepicker.formatDate('ddmmyy', date);
```

It works *now*, because all of your date have two digits in both *day* and *month* components, but it will fail with dates like `01122017`, for example: this function will produce `1122017` key and `checkDateis(dmy)` call will always return `false`.